# How to remove line break that is generated with <ion-fab-button>

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass

I have an app I'm making for my self and I've got two 's with a  in the middle.
The  is auto generating a line break at the end of the button which leaves the UI to look like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uFuj.png)

I've tried adding a css tag to the button and using `display: inline` in the css but that just made the button wider.

Here is the current HTML for the part:

```
<ion-col size="auto">
    <ion-fab-button class="pmButton" (click)="pmOne('-', info.key, info.value.count)" color="danger" >-</ion-fab-button>
    <span class="ion-margin info">{{info.value.count}}  {{itemUnits}}</span>
    <ion-fab-button class="pmButton" (click)="pmOne('+', info.key, info.value.count)" color="success" >+</ion-fab-button>
</ion-col>
```

and the CSS:

```
.pmButton {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.info {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put `display: flex` on the parent element `<ion-col>`, also `flex-direction: row` if its necessary.

If you are unable to do that, due to the fact it's a component, wrap it's content in a div with a class and then apply the CSS above.